# What are the pros and cons of these voxel data file formats?

Tags: animation, data-structure, file-format, voxels, compression

- .VXL
- .VOX
- .KVX
- .KV6
- .V3A
- .V3B

I am trying to decide whether it's worth going with any of the above, or some other, or if I should roll my own. The deciding factors in order of importance are:

1. Animation support (I am aware this is a difficult aspect when it comes to voxels), using voxel deltas or numerical transform descriptions.
2. Simplicity (or at least a concise format)
3. Compression

From what I can tell, the Tiberian Sun VXL format is the only one which is designed for animation, but Ken Silverman of Voxelstein3D fame claimed that VXL does not support animation (in a single file, were his words). So I wonder if maybe there are not two different .VXL formats, since it seems an obvious choice of file extension for voxel data... could be from a medical imaging context.

I do need someone with solid experience of voxel formats to come and comment on the practical pros and cons, in their experience. Consider this question in the same way you might compare JPG to PNG to GIF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The continuation of my comment:

[image: Decision Making Flowchart]

In essence when choosing an existing format these are the problems you must consider:

- Am I saving time by using this?

  - Do I get a editor?
  - Do I get a library to load this from the game media?
- Am I deriving any benefit from using this?

  - Are there clever optimizations in existing libraries?
  - Is the format compact, but not complicated?
- Does this solve my problem in its entirety?

  - Can I use this format with animations?
- Am I forced to use this (interoperability)?

  - Can I open and edit this file in industry-standard programs?

Sitting around figuring out which library to use will probably take longer than just rolling your own. You could probably throw together a basic format in less than a few days and improve it (or replace it) at some point in the future - start solving real problems in your game before wasting time with something game format (but remember, architect your system in such a way that it can be replaced at some point in the future).

Answer (score -1):

am not sure i agree that this was a stupid question to ask... I guess the assumption is you would already have parsed the formats yourself and thus know the differences or some such. But honestly this doesn't seem too different a question to me from asking how different 3d file formats express data (for instance the difference between a .stl or .obj file which is kinda huge depending what you wanna do with them D: and they all have pros and cons etc.

The only one on your list that i have relative experience working with so far is .vox and i know that it can be easily parsed and has plenty of information online for how to do so (have done quite a lot so far with pyvox for instance and it's easily portable to 3d packages including blender via the bpy module. (https://pypi.org/project/Pyvox/) it also includes tools for parsing .vox data.

I've also found it pretty flexible for point cloud animation data. I really like the palette system that it used as integrated with magica voxel and is a very useful way of managing and interpreting color information across platforms (it creates a slot for each palette rather than an assigned colour or material and so is pretty easy to write multiple interpretations depending on what you want it to do..also working with voxel animation this is a huge plus because honestly colour data can sometimes be the trickiest part (again depending on what you are doing and why etc).

i'd be interested also to hear what experiences people have had parsing information from other voxel formats? Also interested in hearing if any of these have some kind of draw or frame output (which would be usfull for animation processing as well).

Comment: also in addition i would reccomend http://www.drububu.com/miscellaneous/voxelizer/index.html?out=xml   which gives very clear and readable examples of each format and additional infromation.